# Redirect Bigcommerce Store to new Shopify Store

Tags: shopify, bigcommerce

I have store in **Bigcommerce** ( e.g: bicommercestore.com ), This is my old store.
Also in **Shopify** ( e.g Shopifystore.com ), This is newly created store.

Both have different works on different domains.

No what i need if someone visit my old Bigcommerce store they redirected to my Shopify store, both in desktop and other devices.
As you know in Bigcommerce their is different templates for both Desktop and mobile.

Please let me know is there and way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a 301 redirect or forward your old domain to your new one. This can be done with the registrar (company you purchased your old domain name from). If you purchased your domain name from Bigcommerce, you will need to login to account.bigcommerce.com and get an EPP transfer code. From there, you would bring this to a registrar and transfer your domain and back the same change.